# Proper Use of -OutVariable in PowerShell

Tags: exchange-2010, powershell

I'm trying to make use of the Common Parameter **OutVariable** in a simple one-liner PowerShell command, but it's not working the way I think it should (or really at all).

```
Get-Mailbox -OutVariable mBoxes | Get-MailboxStatistics | Select-Object DisplayName,TotalItemSize,@{name="ArchiveStatus";Expression={$mBoxes.ArchiveStatus}}
```

I simply want to return 3 columns, with the third column being a property of the results of the initial `Get-Mailbox` command.  I tried to use **OutVariable** to store the results for use in my `Select-Object` command at the end, but that column is always empty when the results print.

Am I not understanding the purpose of **OutVariable**?

BTW, `Get-Mailbox | Select ArchiveStatus` works just fine.

jscott - I simplified the command to the following --

```
get-mailbox -OutVariable mBoxes | Select-Object @{name="Null?";Expression={$mBoxes -eq $null}}
```

I get **True** for every line that Get-Mailbox would return.  It's clearly not storing anything in the **$mBoxes** variable.

Comment: What does `$mBoxes.getType()` show? Is it `ArrayList`?  If it is, you'll either need to index `$mBoxes[0].ArchiveStatus` or walk with `foreach`/`ForEach-Object`.  If you have a hash, use `.GetEnumerator`.

Comment: @uSlackr That's not how to use [`OutVariable`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847884.aspx).

Comment: Oops, you are right.  Deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I think it should work. You missing the fact, that -OutVariable is collection (and not simple array) and it's last element is usually what you are after.

Code that worked for me:

```
Get-Mailbox -OutVariable mBoxes | Get-MailboxStatistics | 
    select DisplayName, TotalItemSize, @{
         Name = 'ArchiveStatus'
         Expression = { $mBoxes.Item($mBoxes.Count - 1).ArchiveStatus
    }
```

That said - I recommend using slightly different technique with Add-Member for that. Can't test performance, but I guess it should be better than collecting whole output from Get-Mailbox...:

```
Get-Mailbox | Foreach-Object { Get-MailboxStatistics -Identity $_ |
    Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ArchiveStatus -Value $_.ArchiveStatus -PassThru } |
    select DisplayName, TotalItemSize, ArchiveStatus
```

Comment: To clarify -- the first example only works when running in a plain vanilla PowerShell window with the Exchange Snapin added.  It will not work in Exchange Management Shell due to the fact that `Get-Mailbox` is a **Function** in EMS and not a **Cmdlet** as when you add the Snapin.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently I *wasn't* misunderstanding how **OutVariable** worked, the issue was due to the fact that I was using the Exchange Management Shell instead of PowerShell with a Snapin.

A somewhat analagous generic example of proper (albeit inane) usage is below --

```
do-something -OutVariable outVar | do-somethingelse | Select-Object Property1,Property2,@{name="CalculatedProperty";Expression={$outVar.Item($outVar.Count - 1).Property}}
```